# android number format

Tags: java

In my app want to round a double to 2 significant figures after decimal point. I tried the code below.

```
public static double round(double value, int places) {
long factor = (long) Math.pow(10, places);
value = value * factor;
long tmp = Math.round(value);
return (double) tmp / factor;
}
```

also i tried

```
double val = ....;
val = val*100;
val = (double)((int) val);
val = val /100;
```

both code do not working for me.

Thanks in advance....

Comment: Can you give an example of incorrect input/output?

Comment: when i give input 0.5, it returns 0.5.Actually i need 0.50 as output. Also when i give input 2.0 i need an output 2.00.

Comment: The number 0.5 is indistinguishable from 0.50, your problem isn't the rounding code, but the code that displays the number.

Comment: what's android for in the title? Is to be retagged?

Comment: Unrelated to your actual problem: the second version of the code should perhaps use `val = val * 100 + 0.5`.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

As Grammin said, if you're trying to represent money, use [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html).  That class has support for all sorts of rounding, and you can set you desired precision exactly.

But to directly answer your question, you can't set the precision on a double, because it's floating point.  It doesn't *have* a precision.  If you just need to do this to format output, I'd recommend using a [NumberFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html). Something like this:

```
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getInstance();
nf.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);
nf.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
String output = nf.format(val);
```

Answer (score 6):

Or you can use a [java.text.DecimalFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/text/DecimalFormat.html):

```
String string = new DecimalFormat("####0.00").format(val);
```

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend using [BigDecimal](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html#ROUND_HALF_EVEN) if you are trying to represent currency.

This [example](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do?Id=13) may be helpful.

Comment: i have also tried the code below.                                                        public static double round(double unrounded)
  {
      BigDecimal bd = new BigDecimal(unrounded);
      BigDecimal rounded = bd.setScale(2, BigDecimal.ROUND_HALF_UP);
      return rounded.doubleValue();
  }

Answer (score 0):

As Gramming suggested you could use BigDecimals for that, or NumberFormat tobe sure about the number of shown figures

Answer (score 0):

Your code appears to work to me

```
double rounded = round(0.123456789, 3);
System.out.println(rounded);

>0.123
```

Edit: just seen your new comment on your question. This is a formatting problem, not a maths problem.

Answer (score 0):

I took the decision to use all as int. In this way no problem.

```
DecimalFormatSymbols currencySymbol = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance();
NumberFormat numberF = NumberFormat.getInstance();
```

after...

```
numberF.setMaximumFractionDigits(2);
numberF.setMinimumFractionDigits(2);

TextView tv_total = findViewById(R.id.total);
int total = doYourStuff();//calculate the prices
tv_total.setText(numberF.format(((double)total)/100) + currencySymbol.getCurrencySymbol());
```